# Why do these both print the same thing?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm really curious why using "remove" isn't actually removing from the list, it would if I declared it in a variable, but then I have another variable to work with and it all becomes very messy, he is my code;

```
    ;;;;Pig latin
(defun pig-latin ()
    (let ((word (read-line)))
        (setf ind-characters (loop for char across word
            collect char))    
        (setf first-char (car ind-characters))
        (setf reversed-word (reverse ind-characters));flips the 
        (remove (last reversed-word) reversed-word)
        (print reversed-word)))
```

The output I get is:

```
(#\d #\r #\o #\w)
(#\d #\r #\o #\w)
```

I would have expected the #\w to be removed from the second part of the output but it doesn't unless I declare it in a variable. How do I just work with a single piece of data and remove/add what I need to it without declaring a lot of variables?

Comment: Why are most of the variables undefined? For example `first-char`? Where is it defined? Why are you calling `remove`, but never use the result? What for is the variable `first-char`? It's not used? What does the function `last` return?

Comment: Because it isn't complete, I hit a snag which is my question, I just added all of the code to make it easier to understand the context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I thought this would have been asked before, and there are certainly relevant things on Stack Overflow, but I didn't find a suitable duplicate.)

The issue is that **remove** returns a new list;  it doesn't *modify* the existing list.  The relevant portion from the HyperSpec entry for [**remove**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm) (emphasis added):

> remove, remove-if, remove-if-not return a sequence of the same type as
>   sequence that has the same elements except that those in the
>   subsequence bounded by start and end and satisfying the test have been
>   removed. **This is a non-destructive operation. If any elements need to
>   be removed, the result will be a copy.** The result of remove may share
>   with sequence; the result may be identical to the input sequence if no
>   elements need to be removed.

This means that you need to use the value returned by **remove**.  E.g., you could return it, bind it to a variable, or assign it to a variable:

```
(defun remove-1 (list)
  (remove 1 list))  ; return the result

(let ((list-without-ones (remove 1 list)))  ; bind the result
  ...)

(setf list (remove 1 list)) ; update a variable
```

Note that the language also includes a **delete** function, which can be destructive.  Note, though, that this doesn't eliminate the need to save the result.  It means that the list structure may be modified.  You still need to save the result, though, because the cons cell that was the first in the old list might not be the cons cell that's the first in the new list.  For more about this, see, for instance:

- [Destructive sorting in lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29712654/1281433)
- [DELETE is destructive -- but not always?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339030/delete-is-destructive-but-not-always)
- [Common Lisp: is delete-if the same as setf + remove-if?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660804/common-lisp-is-delete-if-the-same-as-setf-remove-if)

---

It's also worth noting that many Common Lisp functions operate on *sequences*, not just lists.  Sequences include vectors, of which strings are a subtype.  E.g., **(reverse "word")** will return **"drow"**.  Similarly, you can use **position-if** on sequences.  This means that a simple pig latin function can be done with something like this:

```
(defun vowelp (char)
  (position char "aeiou" :test 'char-equal))

(defun pig-latin (word)
  (let ((i (position-if 'vowelp word))) ; position of first vowel
    (if (null i) word                   ; if no vowels, return word
      (concatenate 'string              ; else, concatenate parts:
                   (subseq word i)      ; * "ord"
                   (subseq word 0 i)    ; * "w"
                   "ay"))))             ; * "ay"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :D The example you gave as how to do a pig latin function has gone way over my head, I'll cross that bridge when I get to it. Thanks!